# can't phone call directly from flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to make a phone call using flutter app; I have found `url_launcher` package. However, it only directs the user to the phone itself and click the green call button to make a regular phone call. Is there a way to make the app call directly and and not using the phone of the user itself?

Answer (score 1):

The method you used for that make android make call.
if you need make call by your own you need implement ui of calling screen and work with [android.telecom](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) .
use https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels to do it yourself by implementing platform-specific code such as CallKit/ConnectionService.